# Infinite loop terminating in pthread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>//getch();
#include <termios.h>//getch();
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);

volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;
int value = 0;
int count = 0;

char getch()
{
    int buf = 0;
    struct termios old = { 0 };
    fflush(stdout);
    if (tcgetattr(0, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr()");
    old.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    old.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    old.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    old.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
    if (read(0, &buf, 1) < 0)
        perror("read()");
    old.c_lflag |= ICANON;
    old.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr ~ICANON");

    return buf;
}
void *send_function(void *parg)
{
    printf("\n Send Thread ");
    count++;
    return parg;
}
void *receive_function(void *parg)
{
    printf("\n Receive Thread ");
    count++;
    return parg;
}
void my_function(int sig)
{
    flag = 1; // set flag
}

int main()
{
    char selection; //user input(s or r)
    pthread_t send;
    pthread_t receive;
    while (1)
    {
        signal(SIGINT, my_function);
        if (flag)
        {
            printf("\n Choose your terminal S or R \n");
            selection = getch();
            flag = 0;
        }
        if (selection == 's')
        {
            if (pthread_create(&send, NULL, send_function, NULL))
            {
                printf("Error creating thread=%d\n", count);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if (selection == 'r')
        {
            if (pthread_create(&receive, NULL, receive_function, NULL))
            {
                printf("Error creating thread=%d\n", count);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        printf("\n MAIN LOOP\n");
        //sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
    //pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Output1 :

```
MAIN LOOP

Receive Thread
MAIN LOOP

Receive Thread
MAIN LOOP

Receive Thread
MAIN LOOP

Receive Thread
Receive Thread
Receive Thread
Receive Thread Error creating thread=380
nivas@balakrishnan-HCL-Desktop:~/C_sample$
```

output2:

```
MAIN LOOP

 MAIN LOOP

 MAIN LOOP

 Send Thread
 Send Thread
 Send Thread
 Send Thread
 Send Thread
 MAIN LOOP
 Error creating thread=379
```

In the above code. the code should run infinitely when I press 's' or 'r' it should print "send thread" or "receive thread" accordingly for infinite number of times whereas in this code approx 380 times only the while loop is running.I don't know why it is happening.I have used variable count for debugging purpose,can anyone help?

Comment: So you create threads infinitely? Threads is a *finite* resource, the operating system will not allow you to create infinite number of threads. You also have to think about how multi-tasking works on operating systems, where all threads and processes *takes turn* to run on the CPU cores. The more threads you have, the less time each have to actually run, and the more time the operating system needs to switch between them.

Comment: If only the documentation for [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html#ERRORS) explained under what conditions it would return an error, how to tell what the error is, and what could cause it. That would be really swell, wouldn't it?

Comment: That's a number that your code chose to log for reasons only you could possibly know. If you don't find it useful, don't log it.

Comment: actually my requirment is to start thread once I press "ctrl+c" and work throughout.for this what should need to do.since thread are not infinite?

Comment: You should: 1) Clean up after yourself. Don't leave threads hanging. 2) Check function calls for errors and handle them sanely.

Comment: And 3) Don't have an infinite loop where you continually check `if (selection == 's')` and create a thread without changing `selection` to something which is *not* `'s'`.

Comment: Furthermore, remember that local variables which are not initialized will have an *indeterminate* value. Don't use them (in any way) without initialization. If you're unlucky the initial value of `selection` might actually *be* `'s'` or `'r'`, which mean you will run out of threads before you even have time to press CTRL-C.

Comment: yeah it is correct @some programmer,I have used pthread detach to solve this problem.after creating a new thread in "cat /proc/17084/status" .I can able to see in number of threads column as '1' instead of '2'(since I have started 2 threads.I have not made any change in the code shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either [detach](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.3.html) your threads or [join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) them. Otherwise, you will run out of resources.

Comment: yeah it will suit my requirment @David Schwartz